# need help about DFT?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I am trying to get the answer from some of my questions:

```
what property of DFT[ax1(n)+bx2(n)] in linearity?

what Fourier transform gives us for an a periodic signal?

what is The magnitude and phase angle?
```